# How to debug Grafana Message templates for alerts?

Tags: grafana, go-templates

I am currently trying to create a Grafana alert for each log in elastic that contains `fields.alert:1`.
[image]

The alert itself works, but now I dont want to use the default message template.
I tried to come up with something like this:

```
{{ define "DefaultElasticAlert.title" }}
{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}⚠️ {{ template "__appname" . }} ⚠️{{ end }}
{{ if eq .Status "resolved" }}✅ {{ template "__appname" . }} ✅{{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ define "DefaultElasticAlert.message" }}
[{{ .Status | toUpper }}] {{ template "__message" . }}
  {{ if eq .Status "firing" }}
    {{ template "__desc" . }}
    {{ template "__recomA" . }}
    {{ template "__category" . }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ define "__appname" }}{{ with index .GroupLabels "fields.AppName.keyword"}}{{ . }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
{{ define "__message" }}{{ with index .GroupLabels "message.keyword"}}{{ . }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
{{ define "__desc" }}{{ with index .GroupLabels "fields.Description.keyword"}}{{ . }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
{{ define "__recomA" }}ToDo: {{ with index .GroupLabels "fields.RecommendedAction.keyword"}}{{ . }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
{{ define "__category" }}Category: {{ with index .GroupLabels "fields.Category.keyword"}}{{ . }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
```

But when I set this as my message template, no alert is logged in my Slack.
When I reset the message template to something simple like this:

```
{{ define "DefaultElasticAlert.title" }}Hello{{ end }}

{{ define "DefaultElasticAlert.message" }}WORLD{{ end }}
```

an alert is logged again.
I tried out a lot of message template, but I can only see of it works, when an alert is logged.
Is there any better way to debug a message template without constantly having to create a new alert and hoping that it gets a message. Is there any kind of error log somewhere, where I can see why a message failed to generate?

Comment: Grafana log's it's errors pretty actively, though I'm not sure it'll errors of the template rendering. Where the logs are depends on your instance: for docker they are in console - see them through docker tools, in local installations they are stored in files by default. On windows default path is `C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\data\log`, on linux `/var/log/grafana` but it can be changed in the configuration.